# Unity Deserialization of nested JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am trying to create a high score system using firebase for a unity project. To retrieve the JSON I am using RESTCLIENT. I have managed to upload the scores fine but deserializing them is proving to be a problem.

```
JSON = "{"UserName1":{"Name":"UN1","ScoreVal":"99/100"},"UserName2":{"Name":"UN2","ScoreVal":"100/100"}}"

[Serializable]
public class RootObject
{
    public Score score { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Score
{
    public string Name;
    public string ScoreVal;

    public Score(string name, string scoreVal)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.ScoreVal = scoreVal;
    }
}
```

The ideal solution would follow this JSON format:

```
{
    "Level1":{
        "User1":{
            "Name":"User1",
            "Score":"100/100"
            },
        "User2":{
            "Name":"User2",
            "Score":"100/100"
            }
        },
    "Level2": {
        "User1": {
            "Name":"User1",
            "ScoreVal":"99/100"
        },
        "User2": {
            "Name":"User2",
            "ScoreVal":"100/100"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using JsonUtility from unity, newtonsoft and my own jsonhelper:

```
public static class JsonHelper2
{
public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
{
    Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(json);
    return wrapper.Items;
}

public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array)
{
    Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
    wrapper.Items = array;
    return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper);
}

public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array, bool prettyPrint)
{
    Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
    wrapper.Items = array;
    return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper, prettyPrint);
}

[Serializable]
private class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T[] Items;
}
```

}

I can retreive data when there is only one entry but I am unable to get scores when there are multiple usernames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json has a fixed number of levels and a fixed number of users. You'd actually require an object like this to deserialize it:

```cs
public class Scores
{
    public Users Level1 {get;set;}
    public Users Level2 {get;set;}
}

public class Users
{
    public User User1 {get;set;}
    public User User2 {get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Score {get;set;}
}
```

Assuming your intention was not to only have 2 fixed levels and 2 fixed users, your json should be structured like this (note that levels are an array and the scores within the level are arrays):

```js
{
    "levels": [{
            "name": "Level 1",
            "scores": [{
                "user": "User1",
                "score": "8/10"
            }, {
                "user": "User2",
                "score": "7/10"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Level 2",
            "scores": [{
                "user": "User1",
                "score": "9/10"
            }, {
                "user": "User3",
                "score": "6/10"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then your C# classes will be:

```cs
public class Score
{
    public string user {get;set;}
    public string score {get;set;}
}

public class Level
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public IList<Score> scores {get;}

    public Level()
    {
        scores = new List<Score>();
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public IList<Level> levels {get;}

    public RootObject()
    {
        levels = new List<Level>();
    }
}
```

If in fact you really are only trying to track 2 fixed levels with the scores for 2 fixed users, your json should work with the initial class structure I presented.

Comment: Hi Colin, thanks for your answer. The problem I am running into is that I do not have a fixed number of users. The levels are fixed at 10 so that isn't so much of a problem as I COULD do what you have described above. Any idea how I could go about making it work for an unspecified number of users?

Comment: The json structure I put in my answer allows an "unlimited" number of levels and an unlimited number of high scores per level. Notice the arrays of `level` objects which themselves contain arrays of `HighScore` objects. How familiar are you with json in general?

Comment: You might find http://json2csharp.com/ helpful. It will generate a C# class for you from a json sample.

Comment: Ah yes, iv just manage to implement it. thank you! This is my first time using json.

Comment: @ColinYoung thank's for the json2csharp tip - nice time saver